# Actioscript Error #2032 only in IE

Tags: actionscript-3

Sorry about my English.

I'm developing a flash application using Flex SDK, it's an actionscript project, not a Flex project. I use `URLLoader` to send an HTTP post request to the server.

In Safari/Chrome, it works fine, but in IE I get this:

```
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error.  URL: https://graph.renren.com/renren_api/session_key"]
```

How can I fix this?
If it works in Safari/Chrome, why it doesn't work in IE?

in my case ,i can't change the server side code, can i fix this just by writing some Actionscript code?

Thanks.

Comment: **"If it works in Safari/Chrome, why it doesn't work in IE?"** You sound like a noob. Get used to IE not working as per standards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This weird problem is kind of popular. It can be fixed by setting cache-control header. It is pretty well described at http://faindu.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/ie7-ssl-xml-flex-error-2032-stream-error/

Comment: in my case ,i can't change the server side code, can i fix this just by writing some Actionscript code?

Comment: Can you try to add a random query to the URL if applicable in your case i.e. `"http://localhost/myRequest?time=" + new Date().time`

Comment: i'm using post method,and URLVariables to pass params. How can i use your code?